# Prolog: Попадает ли точка в круг

Tags: геометрия, prolog, gnu-prolog

Написал на ПРОЛОГЕ программу, которая определяет попала ли точка с координатами в круг. Программа выводит верно если точка в круге, а если нет, то всё равно выводит "Попадает", а точка не в круге.

Привожу код, подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело.

```
domains
n=real
predicates
proverka(n,n,n,n,n)
proverka1(n,n,n,n,n)
clauses
proverka(X,Y,Xc,Yc,R):- sqrt((X-Xc)*(X-Xc) + (Y-Yc)*(Y-Yc))<=R*R, write("Popadaet").
proverka1(X,Y,Xc,Yc,R):- sqrt((X-Xc)*(X-Xc) + (Y-Yc)*(Y-Yc))>R*R, write("Ne popadaet").
goal
write("Vvedite X= "),readreal(X),
write("Vvedite Y= "),readreal(Xc),
write("Vvedite Xc= "),readreal(Y),
write("Vvedite Yc= "),readreal(Yc),
write("Vvedite R= "),readreal(R),proverka(X,Y,Xc,Yc,R),proverka1(X,Y,Xc,Yc,R).
```

Comment: У вас проблема, кхм, не совсем с Прологом. Уверены, что `R*R`? Сравните размерности / единицы измерения.

Comment: ввожу только цифры и всё.

Comment: Э-э-э... Вы собственный код читали вообще?

Comment: Условие попадание точки в круг `X^2+y^2 <= R^2` У Вас получается, X^2+Y^2 <= R^4 если корни убрать

Answer (score 0):

Вот у вас код:

```
sqrt((X-Xc)*(X-Xc) + (Y-Yc)*(Y-Yc))<=R*R
```

> Условие попадание точки в круг X^2+y^2 <= R^2
>   У Вас получается, X^2+Y^2 <= R^4 если корни убрать

Должно же быть

```
sqrt((X-Xc)*(X-Xc) + (Y-Yc)*(Y-Yc))<=R
```

или

```
(X-Xc)*(X-Xc) + (Y-Yc)*(Y-Yc)<=R*R
```